# Custom search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, form-submit

I created a custom template in which i need create a search form and display the results in a simple list. I tried to create the form in this way:

```
<form role="form" action="../wp-content/api/search-json.php?key" method="post" id="searchform"> 
    <div class="form-group">

        <input id="search-protocol" type="text" class="form-control" name="typeahead"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cerca</button>
</form>
```

and the search-json.php page is this:

```
<?php


    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
    global $wpdb;
    $key=$_GET['key'];

        $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM list WHERE code LIKE '%{$key}%'");

        $json = $wpdb->last_result;
        echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

But i can't show the results. I need a very simple list.

Answer (score 0):

Your form must be with GET method if you want handle $_GET['key'] . Or you can change it to $key = $_POST['key'].

Also I not view where in your form input for $key variable.  It should be something like

```
<input id="search-protocol" type="text" class="form-control" name="key"/>
```

So at last we have

```
<form role="form" action="../wp-content/api/search-json.php" method="post" id="searchform"> 
    <div class="form-group">

        <input id="search-protocol" type="text" class="form-control" name="key"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cerca</button>
</form>
```

try in your PHP file :

```
$prepare = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE code LIKE %s", $key); 
$results = $wpdb->get_results($prepare);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: If i change in $key = $_POST['key'] i get an internal server error :( and how can i put the result in a list under the input?

Comment: Ok sorry i forgot the ";" after $key = $_POST['key'].. But it redirect me in the page with the json and without filtering the query.. i need show a list underst the input filtering for the value that i have written in the input

Comment: On these page in JSON is results of your query? Do you change name of your input field?

Comment: I'm using your form now.but simple brings me in search-json.php page with the entire json. It seems the query is simply SELECT * FROM list without any WHERE condition

Comment: Please check - maybe your table contains prefix.

Also try $prepare = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE code LIKE %s", $key);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($prepare);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use get_search_form, a wordpress's function.

[@codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)

You can override the function if you want, just create a searchform.php in your theme.